# In jQuery, how to test whether an element is the first of many elements of same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 div's:

```
<div class='squares' id='div1'></div>
<div class='squares' id='div2'></div>
<div class='squares' id='div3'></div>
```

With jQuery, I would like to apply a css property (a border-right) to all div's, except the first one.

What is the if statement that I should use? I want to use the class in the if statement (not the id's).

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:not()` and `:first` selectors:

```
$('.squares:not(:first)').addClass('border')
```

or:

```
$('.squares:not(:first)').css('border-right', 'value')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I just have a little syntax problem, because I'm using the `this` selector. How do I combine with `:not(:first)`? Is it `$(this + ':not(:first)')`. This didn't work. THanks

Comment: `this` is the context, so put it where the context goes. `$('selector', context)`

Comment: @eric01 Hi, You are welcome, `:not` doesn't work that way, if you want to deselect the first element and your elements are siblings, you can try this: `if( $(this).index() != 0 )`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tied using [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selectors ?

I haven't tested, but the following code should do what you want:

```js
$(".squares:not(:first)").css("border-right", "thin solid red");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.is()` in your `if` statement:

```
if (!$(this).is(".squares:first()")) {
    // not the first square 
}
```